# Performing XML Request with HttpClient in .NET 4.5 +

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have written a following code to perform an XML request using .NET's HttpWebClient library like this:

```
 public async Task<string> DoRequest()
        {

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string requestXML = "My xml here...";
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "example.com");
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestXML, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

And in the main function of the console application:

```
 Klijent test= new Klijent();
 var res = test.DoRequest();
```

But the res return type is always showing me this:

```
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

How do I actually perform the request with this library? What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply wait for result

```
var res = test.DoRequest().Result;
```

You are expecting immediate result, even though you code is asynchronous.

Comment: Ah thats it... Ty so much :) :)

Comment: Or use `res= await test.DoRequest();`. You only need `.Result` in methods where you can't use `async`, like the Main method of a console application